# Employing a deforming mesh, inlet, and no shear wall in ANSYS

Tags: fluid-mechanics, ansys, fluent

I am interested in running a simulation in ANSYS Fluent (or CFX, whichever is more useful) that combines the following.

**Update:**

- A rotating wing in the air, similar to a turbine blade. **After experimenting with a sliding grid I've come to the conclusion a deforming grid around a stationary wing would be better.**
- A velocity inlet that is attached to the wing at the base. **This mimics the rotating wing.**
- A no-shear surface at the inlet.

As stated above I have found several tutorials showing how to create a sliding grid model; however, **having the mesh deform instead would allow the inlet to remain fixed and that would be better.**

Finally, the velocity inlet that I envision will need to be a solid surface, and I don't want that to influence the flow, so that would need to have no shear on the surface.

I have included two images showing what I am trying to model with ANSYS.

[image]

- The blue is the inlet velocity wall, and the red arrow represents the velocity.
- The yellow represents the walls with no shear. ***I am unsure how to implement this and would appreciate some specific guidance and recommendations.***

[image: rotating mesh with stationary wing]

**Update:**

- The blue lines represent a larger course mesh (not to scale).
- The red lines represent a smaller fine mesh (cylindrical in shape to allow the region to rotate, notice the green arrow is pointing opposite to the first figure). **This is similar to a sliding mesh, but the wing in black should stay fixed with the mesh deforming as the flow rotates.** ***I am unsure how to implement this and would appreciate some specific guidance and recommendations.***

Comment: Sometimes tutorials for special situations don’t exist. Means you have to do it yourself.

Comment: Yes, but is it even possible to combine these "special situations" with commercial software?

Comment: Yes, seen simulations of blood flow through a heart and smoke propagation across a town using CFD like StarCD, Phoenics etc

Comment: I only have access to ANSYS software. I'm not looking for a tutorial for this specific situation. If anything I'm looking for guides to combine pieces together, but even that would only be the first step.